# exec() call to unknown plugin: StatusBarNotification

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I don't know why the plugin manager throw exec() call to unknown plugin: StatusBarNotification, I downloaded a example and tried to make it equal, but I couldn't. 
 I am using phonegap 3.5

config.xml

```
    <plugin name="StatusBarNotification" value="com.phonegap.plugins.statusBarNotification.StatusBarNotification"/>
```

index.html

```
 <body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
             <button onclick="sendNotification()"> Mensaje</button>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/statusbarnotification.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function sendNotification() {  
            window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Sample Notification", "mensajito");
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the plugin you are using is not for Cordova/PhoneGap >= version 3.0.

Since 3.0, everything should be done via the CLI, including installing plugins: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

You then don't include references to any plugin javascript, as Cordova takes care of this.

You can search for compatible plugins on either of these 2 sites:

- http://plugreg.com
- http://plugins.cordova.io

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks that clarify me how I have to use the plugins on cordoba > 3 and I used this plugin and was very easy thanks